# How to change the first element of a List from 0 to 1? And how to overlook an empty List?

Tags: c#, list

The program continues when the user enters 0, I want to enter 1 for the first element of the list.

Also what do I have to do if the `courselist` is empty?

```
    Console.WriteLine("Give course");
    int y;

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y) || y >= Helper.courselist.Count() || y < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give course that already created (1,2,3,...etc)");
    }
```

Comment: If you are learning C# try not to write everything in one line. so that you can debug it and wrap your head around it easier. It's more readable and it will be excatly the same from performance point of view.

Comment: @Bizhan that's a good rule in general, and not just for learners!

Comment: @Bizhan I dont write everything in one line. I just didnt post correct the code. Now its fine.

Comment: I didn't mean "everything" as in "not using \r\n"! I mean your loop termination condition is doing at least 6 different things in one statement.

Comment: @Bizhan I see what you mean. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if (courselist.Count() == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please add course first");
    ShowMenu2();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give course");

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y)
           || y >= courselist.Count() + 1 || y <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give course that already created (1,2,3,...etc)");
    }

    ShowMenu2();
}
```